# nvidia driver ubunu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm trying to configure my Dell XPS to use the nvidia graphics card that came with it.

I've followed various tutorials into installing the drivers: (https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-nvidia-driver-ubuntu-18-04) but the driver is not being loaded.

I've disabled Secure Boot as well, but still the driver doesn't load:

```
$nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

I wasn't sure if it was a kernel issue as i was running 5.8, so i also installed 5.9 and still get the same issue

I've tired purging nvidia, use the nouveau and xorg driver, but with no luck

Any other methods are much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

from GUI:

Open the Software & Updates application window. Select TAB Additional Drivers and choose any proprietary NVIDIA driver. The higher the driver number the latest the version.

[image]

from terminal:

```
 $ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-450
```

Once the installation is concluded, reboot your system and you are done.

NOTE: as you can see I have also the same your message at command nvidia-smi but nvidia driver it is installed. I'have had an issue installing NVIDIA drivers, but was related to wrong grub configuration. I've tested Kernel 5.8.2 and also 5.8.14 and nvidia driver works.

[image]